# Spring MVC Redirect for Many URLs

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a web application with over 300 old urls to new URL's. As there are no consistenty patterns, I believe I can't use the URL Rewrite Filter. Some of these are 301's and others are 302's.

At this point, the only thing I think is basically have a controller with all these urls(there are over 300 URL's) and do a redirect reading from a properties files. I am not real comfortable with this and would appreciate if there was a better approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

May it would be possible to have some patterns and some explicit mapping (properties file) for the urls that do not match the patterns.

So if there is an request, first check the explicit mappings. If there is no explicit mapping, then use the "default" pattern way.

---

On the otherhand you are right: If there is no way a computer can not compute the mapping by some rules, then there is no way. *(If something looks complicated than may it is complicated.)*